# ATI Radeon HD 3400 crashing Windows XP Desktop

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, freeze, amd-radeon

Two Windows XP desktops have recently had ATI Radeon HD 3400 graphics cards installed.  Both have since had issues where the OS freezes, intermittently.

We installed the latest drivers from the ATI website.  There is nothing in the Event Log, and Device Manager shows no driver issues.

Any ideas if this is a compatibility issue?  Is there a software fix?

Comment: occasionally a driver other than the latest can fix odd problems like this. See if older drivers fix it. Also check for overheating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the graphics card did come with a driver disc, which resolved the problem for us.